# Book I read in 2004-05 about a scary energy ball that can communicate

Tags: story-identification, books

It's been about 20 years so I barely remember, but the story was about an ominous maybe alien maybe floating ball of something? I think it wanted to destroy or consume the Earth. And it could communicate with people. And it maybe had a young girl protagonist (or maybe I just think that because I was a young girl when I read it...)

It had a blue cover. I may be remembering it incorrectly, so the details may be wrong.

Comment: Any chance you're remembering the story "Dune Roller" by Julian May? This story concerns a fifteen foot diameter ball of a living, alien, metal-like substance in Lake Michigan. The alien could generate burning energy from its matter. No human communication in that story, however.

Answer (score 9):

[So You Want to Be a Wizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_You_Want_to_Be_a_Wizard) by Diane Duane (first book of her Young Wizards series) has a 13 year old girl protagonist (Nita), and a sentient white hole (Fred) who talks. Fred doesn't want to destroy anything but his long term presence is definitely harmful to the surroundings (he keeps *producing* things. Like pens, and radiation).

Some editions have blue covers:

[image: cover art]

Comment: Fred is definitely a hero in this book.  He makes a mess once or twice but there is never any doubt about his motivation.  (Sorry, just have to stick up for Fred - he can't help that Nita's pen is causing problems with his gnaester.)

Answer (score 6):

It could be [***"Masquerade"***](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v27n01_1941-03_Gorgon776_starhome/page/n56/mode/1up) by ***Clifford Simak***, aka ***"Operation Mercury"***.

[image]

Story is about energy station on Mercury, and there are these **balls-like** sentient energy beings, that wanted to **eliminate men** on that station.
Balls can communicate with the men, turn into anything and read your thoughts.

[Full text at archive.org](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v27n01_1941-03_Gorgon776_starhome/page/n56/mode/1up)